# Filtering List data using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

In this code I have declared `myPushData`, `myPushDataFilterd` and `myPushDataFilterd2` variables which are using in code. I am thinking this code could be more easy & short

```
private async void SendPushNotificationHwCreate(string orgId, string classId, string sectionId)
{
    var myPushData = new List<pushTokens>();
    var myPushDataFilterd = new List<pushTokens>();
    var myPushDataFilterd2 = new List<pushTokens>();


    var abtDAL = new AboutDAL();
    var orDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
          { "orgId",SISConst.LoggedInUser.LogInOrganizationID},
        };
    var response = await SisApi.Get("Homework/GetOrganizationName", orDetails);
    var jres = JArray.Parse(response);
    var orgName = jres[0]["Title"].Value<string>();
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic.Add("id", orgId);
    dic.Add("classId", classId);
    dic.Add("sectionId", sectionId);
    var result = SisApi.Get("Notifications/GetPNToken", dic, out bool isSuccess);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        myPushData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<pushTokens>>(result);
        myPushDataFilterd= myPushData.Where(i => i.OrgClassLevelID == Convert.ToInt32(classId)).ToList();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sectionId))
            myPushDataFilterd2= myPushDataFilterd.Where(i => i.OrgSectionLevelID == Convert.ToInt32(sectionId)).ToList();
    }

    var pushTask = new Task(() =>
    {
        if (isSuccess && myPushDataFilterd2.Any())
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < myPushDataFilterd2.Count; index++)
            {
                var row = myPushDataFilterd2[index];
                var osType = row.OSType;
                var to = row.PNToken;
                var studentId = row.StudentID;
                var jGcmData = new JObject();
                var jData = new JObject();
                var api = string.Empty;

                jData.Add("moduleName", "Homework");
                jData.Add("classId", classId);
                jData.Add("sectionId", sectionId);
                jData.Add("bodyText", "New homework assigned");
                jData.Add("organization", orgName);
                jData.Add("organizationId", orgId);
                jData.Add("studentId", studentId);
                jGcmData.Add("to", to);
                jGcmData.Add("data", jData);
                jGcmData.Add("priority", "high");
                api = row.ServerKeyPush;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(api))
                    api = SISConst.API_KeyAndroidFCM;

                var url = new Uri("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                try
                {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
                            "Authorization", "key=" + api);
                        var r = client.PostAsync(url,
                            new StringContent(jGcmData.ToString(), Encoding.Default, "application/json")).Result;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Something went wrong", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    var objLog = new LogService();
                    objLog.MobileLog(ex, SISConst.UserName);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    pushTask.Start();
}
```

`SendPushNotificationHwCreate`  is a method to send *notifications*, in `myPushData`  I am getting records from all `class` & `sections`. Now for filtering I am using above three variables which doesn't seems good way to do that. It looks like am making it complicated. Is this code could be reduced.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain (in words) what this code is achieving, and could you elaborate on how this fits into the whole application? For example, is this a whole method, and what is it's job? Whence does `classId` come? It's hard to provide commentary when we can't see the concrete usage (e.g. the `//something..` might have important consequences for a review).

Comment: @VisualMelon - This method is for sending push notifications, sending class & section Ids while calling this method. Please see my edits. Thank you

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels that I don't even know where to start... Not awating the final task? Is this really what you want? Using the `HttpClient` in a loop. Using `.Result` on `PostAsync`.

Comment: @t3chb0t - Thank you for your input  _Not awaiting final task_, what is final task? I will look at `.Result` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First doesn't seem like any of this code is used.  I mean it gets called but nothing with the responses is used in the code following the calls.

```
var abtDAL = new AboutDAL();
var orDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
      { "orgId",SISConst.LoggedInUser.LogInOrganizationID},
    };
var response = await SisApi.Get("Homework/GetOrganizationName", orDetails);
var jres = JArray.Parse(response);
var orgName = jres[0]["Title"].Value<string>();
```

Async void methods are a code smell, it's not recommended.

Also on myPushDataFilterd you don't need to do ToList you can just leave them as IEnumerable.  You won't need the var myPushDataFilterd2.

You have what seems like a bug in your task code.  You check for myPushData.Any() but are looping around the filtered pushdata. Also

```
var row = myPushData[index];
```

would be wrong because again looping around the filtered data.  I assume you want the myPushDataFilterd2[index].

Also more bugs you are checking string.IsNullOrEmpty(sectionId) to fill myPushDataFilterd2.  If there is no sectionId passed in then myPushDataFilterd2 will be empty and your loop will just exit.  I assume that is not what you want.

HttpClient should be created once and then used for the entire loop and not created each time.

I would move the entire task code into it's own method passing in parameters and making it async. I don't see the need to create a Task object and start it.

Also move the check for Any and IsSuccessful out of the task.  Why create an object that will not do anything?

UPDATE based on comment

```
var pushTask = new Task(() =>
{
    if (isSuccess && myPushDataFilterd2.Any())
```

should be changed to this *if you leaving it to create a task object*

```
if (isSuccess && myPushDataFilterd2.Any())
{
    var pushTask = new Task(() =>
    {
```

As there is no processing done in the task if either of those are false.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So many things you have pointed but few I didn't get like in last `Why create an object that will not do anything?` and `I would move the entire task code into it's own method passing in parameters and making it async. I don't see the need to create a Task object and start it` Can you please modify my code

Comment: You can move the if (isSuccess && myPushDataFilterd2.Any()) out side of the task object.  No point in creating the task object if it's not going to do anything.    Also instead of creating a task object to run the code just create another async task method and put that code in there.

Comment: Thank you. My concern is _How you can say task object not doing anything_, in what situation it would do something. Also you can look at my updated code in question.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show exactly what I was talking about.